# Visual studio: zooming design view for asp.net pages

Tags: visual-studio, high-dpi, visual-studio-2017

I use Visual Studio 2017 (Community Ed.) to design asp.net websites.
When working in design view on a high-dpi-screen, the pages appear tiny, that is: they are rendered 1px=1px, without any display scaling.

Is there any way to zoom the view? 
CTRL-+ doesn't work.
Mouse-zoom doesn't work.

If not, is there a way to change how Visual Studio handles the display scaling (a .manifest hack, or similar?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official answer of Microsoft, via the Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/97404/design-view-is-not-dpi-scaled-and-cannot-be-zoomed.html), is : ".. The Design View is based on very old technology and we’re not investing in it at this time. However, we are investigating a new browser-based design experience that will do a better job keeping up with evolving Web standards. ..", as well as: ".. We have determined that this issue will not be addressed in the upcoming release. We will continue to evaluate it for future releases. .."